# iOS XMPP vs WebRTC, which should I use?

Tags: ios

I  want to build an iOS application that people can video call or audio call to each other. Stable calling is my goal, and it means I need less connection interrupt as much as good, I also need light application (not too high application size because of video libraries)

I've googled about "ios video chat' keywords since last few days. Researched and found that the most popular framework (technology, library) for video/audio calling are XMPP and WebRTC (I'm I right or do guys have something better?)

*XMPP* - Client/server TCP communication

*WebRTC* - P2P Connection

The information about these libraries make me confused, so which library I should use for better performance, light application, stable?

Any idea?

Comment: take a look https://xmpp.org/uses/webrtc.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XMPP is about signaling (reaching from A to B, indicating the desire to have a "call", disconnecting, etc).
WebRTC is about media (actually sending voice and video).

You need both signaling and media in your app.

For media use WebRTC. There's nothing else that will make sense. On iOS, it is kind of tricky at the moment, as iOS 11 incorporates WebRTC already, so how this will apply and help you in your development is yet to be seen ([see here](https://bloggeek.me/webrtc-ios-support/)).
My suggestion is to aim for a web app and then figure out if you need to go for a fully native implementation and port WebRTC to iOS - or just use a webview inside an app (Cordova or Crosswalk should do).

For signaling, you can use XMPP. Or anything else for that matter. My own personal preference is a proprietary protocol. Look at [Matrix](http://matrix.org/) or [SimpleWebRTC](https://simplewebrtc.com/) for that.

Also - don't forget that you will need to deal with STUN and TURN - NAT traversal, but that's a simpler thing to handle.

Comment: This is the answer I waiting for, thanks for your time

Comment: You might want to take this quick free course on server side in WebRTC - it should clarify this further for you - https://bloggeek.me/webrtcs-server-side-enroll/

Answer (score 0):

XMPP Framework: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/IntroToFramework

WebRTC Native Code: https://webrtc.org/native-code/ios/

its not about which is best its about what fulfills our requirements